Is there consensus on the mechnism of alkyne halogenation?
Alkyne halogenation is usually said to occur via a mechanism that involves a halonium ion intermediate. However, in David Klein's Organic Chemistry (4th ed., 2020), he writes "The mechanism of alkyne halogenation is not entirely understood." without commenting further.
What is Klein referring to here? It sounds like there is no consensus on the mechanism. Or is the book just outdated on this part?

There's a difference between suspected and confirmed mechanism.
